# Reason for application using OpenGL accumulation buffer not looking correct

Tags: opengl

I have an OpenGL example I wrote years ago demonstrating the lense effect using the accumulation buffer.
I compile it under linux, works fine.

I cross compile it to windows (gentoo crossdev, i686-mingw32). I start it with wine and on a separate laptop running windows. It looks wrong, it looks like the image did not get accumulated but only the last rendered image was used.

Could this be, because the platforms do not support the accumulation buffer?
I want to exclude that it could be because something goes wrong during cross compilation.

- Can I somehow test if the windows platform/wine supports the accumulation buffer?
- Anyone knows a (precompiled!) example program using the accumulation buffer I could run to test if it has to do with my way of compiling?

Thanks!
Nathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `GL_ACCUM_[RED|BLUE|GREEN]_BITS` via [`glGet()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGet.xml) to make sure you actually got an accumulation buffer.

Comment: Hey,

good Idea, I do this:
    
    int bits;
    glGetIntegerv(GL_ACCUM_RED_BITS, &bits);
    printf("Bits: %i\n",(int)bits);

Strangely, the output is "Bits: 0" on a system where accumulation works.

Comment: That's odd.  Are you calling that with an active OpenGL context?

Comment: No, I did not. And doing so helped :).

Answer (score 0):

On win32 you have to check the `PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd368826(VS.85).aspx